# Modifying a WP_Query Request join condition

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue and have tried a lot of methods to solve it -

What I'm trying to do is modify a WordPress WP_Query before it runs: to query based on a post's parent ID rather than it's own ID. To be specific, I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,2) 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (35)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product_variation' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 12;
```

The posts passed in are woocommerce product variations. The issue is that I want to return all product variations within the specific taxonomy, but the term_taxonomy_id of 35 is referenced only by the parent. So in the first join condition above, I believe I need:

```
ON(wp_posts.post_parent = wp_term_relationship.object_id)
```

Should be easy enough, but I can't figure out a way to modify this query suitably before it runs. Here are some things I have tried:

The tax_query has a primary_id_column that seems like it would be the right value to modify. I tried modifying the args before creating the query like this:

```
$args['tax_query']['primary_id_column'] = 'post_parent';
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In this case, the query vars are not modified whatsoever. I also tried several ways of modifying primary_id_column after the object is created, like these:

```
$wp_query->tax_query->primary_id_column = 'post_parent';
$wp_query->tax_query->get_sql('wp_posts', 'post_parent');
$wp_query->set('primary_id_column','post_parent');
```

These do in fact modify the query vars, but no matter what - the $wp_query->request string always contains the join condition on wp_posts.ID rather than wp_posts.post_parent. I wondered if at the point I make these changes the query has already been generated and isn't changed before I get the posts. I tried running the above lines in a hook for this reason, using:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_use_parent' );
```

But no luck. If anybody has a suggestion for how I could modify the join condition in this query, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a ton in advance.